# What is DateMath as used in solr index documents to query based on timestamp?

Tags: date, search, solr, lucene

Here is an example of a date math string used to query documents based on a time range

```
timestamp:[2016-07-15T02:44:33.764Z TO 2016-07-15T02:44:33.800Z]
```

I also see usages of NOW like [* TO NOW], where is all the available strings documented? Also, is Date Math a type of formatting that is recognized by certain Date field types?

Comment: would have been faster just to google it: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working with dates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates): Solr only supports ISO-8601 formatted dates and timestamps:

> The format used is a restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime in the XML Schema specification – a restricted subset of ISO-8601.  For those familiar with Java 8, Solr uses DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT for formatting, and parsing too with "leniency".
>
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

NOW is a special value as it's evaluated to the current timestamp, in general - it's bad for caching and might not be required (i.e. if you're querying a busy index, you might want to use a value rounded up or down instead).

All timestamps can be modified [using the Date Math syntax supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates), where you can round a value to a specific unit or add / subtract units as required:

> For example: this represents a point in time two months from now:
>
> `NOW+2MONTHS`
>
> This is one day ago:
>
> `NOW-1DAY`
>
> A slash is used to indicate rounding. This represents the beginning of the current hour:
>
> `NOW/HOUR`
>
> The following example computes (with millisecond precision) the point in time six months and three days into the future and then rounds that time to the beginning of that day:
>
> `NOW+6MONTHS+3DAYS/DAY`

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!